# Work Item naming conventions

Tags: project-management, tfs-workitem

What naming conventions do you use when creating work items in your task/bug tracking tools?

For example:

- Do you prefix the items with an area/subject?
- How do you begin scenarios/use cases? E.g., "The department manager can..."
- How do you make it easier to detect duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project management, bug tracking and time management (if different from the pm tool) should follow the same pattern, no matter what the pattern is.  I usually like to do a top down approach: project-application-page (for example: Amazon-Order Entry-Confirmation Page) - if the project/task management, bug and time management all follow the same pattern then you can track tasks to open issues to time spent easily. After the page you enter a short descriptive text of the issue.  In the description area, you need to state:

- environment (OS/browser)
- version being tested
- server environment (dev, QA, or production)
- the bug (screen captures help greatly)
- the expected results (what you expected to happen)
- level of issue (show stopper to nice-to-have-but-will-never-get-done)